# Using a vector of structs in a struct in c++/cx

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have a header file defining some structs I want to use in my code.

```
public value struct HttpHeader
{
   Platform::String^ mName;
   Platform::String^ mValue;

};
typedef Platform::Collections::Vector<HttpHeader> HttpHeaders;

public value struct HttpRequestEvent
{
   Platform::String^ mUri;
   HttpHeaders^ mHeaders;
};
```

When I build this I get this error:

```
error C3986: 'mHeaders': signature of public member contains native type 'std::equal_to<_Ty>'
      with
      [
          _Ty=cpcpb::HttpHeader
      ] (SettingsServiceImpl.cpp)
```

What am I missing here? Isn't everything I'm using C++/Cx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector` instead of `Platform::Collections::Vector`.

To use `Platform::Collections::Vector` you have to provide a custom comparator which is the equals operator.

Check this link - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/5ec2090f-b7e6-40e8-9cd7-75cf36d05ab3/

Comment: Futhermore, in C++/Cx, value types (value struct/value class) should only contain fundamental types, String^, and other value types.  Other types are not permitted (at least by the RTM compiler, it is possible that with earlier releases the compiler incorrectly permits this).

Comment: So because IVector is not a fundamental type, my HttpRequestEvent struct isn't allowed.

Is there a way to have a vector in a value struct then?

Comment: I do not believe there is a way to accomplish this.  Is there a reason you cannot make HttpReqeustEvent a ref struct/class?