# How to bind Platform::Collections::Vector to a gridview

Tags: xaml, data-binding, collections, uwp, c++-cx

im trying to bind a Platform::Collections::Vector to a GridView but i get a compile-time error by Visual Studio:

```
C3986 'get':the signature of the public member contains a native type 'std::equal_to<T>'
C3986 'get':the signature of the public member contains a native type 'std::equal_to<T>'
C3986 'get':the signature of the public member contains a native type 'std::equal_to<T>'
C3986 'get':the signature of the public member contains a native type 'std::equal_to<T>'
```

NavigationPage.xaml.h

```
[Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
public ref class NavigationPage sealed
{
public:
    NavigationPage();
    property Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>^ ImagesProperty
    {
        Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>^ get()
        {
            if (Images == nullptr) Images = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>();
            return this->Images;
        };
    }


private:
    Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>^ Images;
};
```

NavigationPage.xaml

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="View" ItemSource="{x:Bind ImagesProperty}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I already tried to search on Google, but the majority of example i found were made with C# and if for c++ they target Windows 8/8.1 so as last resource i decided to ask here.

Target Build: 10586, Minimum Build: 10586

Comment: Does this address the issue? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11770357/424129

Comment: well, im having trouble implementing Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector, but by your answer can i suppose that the rest of the code syntactically is fine?

Comment: I'm too rusty on C++ to comment on that.

Comment: problem resolved thanks for your help :D

Comment: Unless this question is a duplicate of the one linked to by EdPlunkett, you should add an answer (see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may encounter my same problem here is the code, thanks to the link Ed Plunkett posted i was able to make it work, the problem was the class Platform::Collections::Vector(details on the his link)

```
public:
    NavigationPage();
    property Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Platform::String^>^ ImagesProperty 
    {
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Platform::String^>^ get() 
        {
            if (Images == nullptr) Images = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>();
            return Images;
        }
    }
private:
    Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>^ Images;
};
```

as you can see i implicitily casted the Vector class as IObservableVector

Comment: You were getting the error because Platform::Vector is a concrete C++ type that implements IVector. Collections in XAML when binding to an IVector will internally attempt to cast to the type IBindableObservableVector (which in an interface that they understand how to bind to), this is specifically to support C++/CX databinding scenarios.